# Is it possible to restrict kubernetes dns resolution to return instance on same node as pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a setup where we're running `telegraf` and the pod is configured as a daemon set in rancher (so instance per node.) Now when doing `nslookup` over the alias in any container, dns resolution returns all ips of all instances on all nodes. Is it possible to restrict this to just the node the workload is running on?

Reason to ask is that in some containers, there is a udp socket send_to, which for some reason seems to resolve all ips and then attempt to connect to all of them before writing the data.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation you can setup - Pod’s DNS Policy **`dnsPolicy: Default`**

> Note: “**Default” is not the default DNS policy**. If dnsPolicy is not
> explicitly specified, then “**ClusterFirst” is used**.
>
> If a Pod’s **dnsPolicy is set to “default”**, **it inherits the name resolution**
> configuration **from the node** that the Pod runs on. The Pod’s DNS resolution
> should behave the same as the node.:

Additional information you can find here: [inheriting-dns-from-the-node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#inheriting-dns-from-the-node)